# passing array post values jquery ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I spend my all day in searching of this solutions but i didn't find any proper way to do this.
i am beginner with jquery need code help.

i have a dynamic table in a form which will send bed details to php.
its diagram is like this. numbers below user choose from select dropdown box.

```
Rooms     | King Bed | Queen Bed | Child Bed
--------------------------------------------------
Room Name |   1      |    0      |   0
Room Name2|   0      |    1      |   0
Room Name3|   0      |    0      |   2
```

its not a single form many of other inputs are before it and after it.
so i dont think so we can use serialize() with jquery etc..
the thing which i really hate in jquery ajax is we can't pass $_POST['txt'] array of form to php.
need you help with how can i pass each room detail to php.

waiting for positive response.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't post arrays through ajax. You just can't use a native object, pass a string instead.

```
$.post('mypage.php', 'txt[]=a&txt[]=b&txt=c')
```

More info at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**NOTE:** You may need to escape the *[* and *]* which become *%5B* and *%5D*, respectively.

Comment: i can't do like this as i already explained that this is dynamic table not static.
so i am using in names like this
name=bedname[]
name=kingsize[]
so on...
means four columns are repeating in loop.
now how can i save it?

Comment: You'll have to encode it manually. If you need to send two rooms, it's like this: `room[1]['type']=smoking&room[1]['number']=901&room[2]['type']=non+smoking&room[2]['number']=123`